# Python setup.py: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow')

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I have `tensorflow` listed as a requirement in the `install_requires` section of the `setup.py` of my project.

When I attempt to install my project into a new Anaconda environment I get the following error:

```
$ python setup.py install

...

Searching for tensorflow
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/
No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow')
```

I can get past this by installing tensorflow "manually" via conda:

```
$ conda install tensorflow
```

Once I do this the install via `setup.py` works without a hitch.

Am I mistaken in assuming that something is amiss with my environment? If not then what is going on and how can I avoid this issue? (My concern is that users of my package will not be able to install from source using `setup.py`)

Another oddity that I assume is related or may provide a clue is that the version of TensorFlow listed in my Anaconda environment is 2.0 but if I import it when running Python it appears to instead be using version 1.15. For example:

```
$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/james/miniconda3/envs/cvdata_test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.0.0           mkl_py37h66b46cc_0  
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           mkl_py37h9204916_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.0              pyh2649769_0  

$ python 
Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan  7 2020, 22:33:48) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.15.0-rc2'
```

This is on a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 without a GPU, so perhaps the version shown in the interpreter is akin to `tensorflow-cpu`? If I run `pip freeze` I see `tensorflow==2.0.0` and `tensorflow-cpu==1.15.0rc2`, which is a bit confusing...

Comment: For this error "error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow')" make sure you have an upgraded (latest) version of pip.

Comment: I also have this error: WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
The instructions contained in the referenced issue are all over the place and nothing looks conclusive so I'm hesitant to go down a rabbit hole...

Comment: It looks like you may have dependency clashes. Try using an Anaconda virtual environment, `conda create ....` that will force a single version of `pip` and `python`.

Comment: Yes, I have been using conda to create a fresh virtual environment. I get the above mentioned errors with `$ python -m pip install -e .` or `$ python -m pip install tensorflow`. I must first do `conda install tensorflow` then everything will work more or less as expected. Maybe it has something to do with where pip looks for packages, akin to how you can set channels for conda? My assumption is that it's going to PyPI for tensorflow and it should be there, so maybe I've somehow goobered where it looks for packages? Funny how tensorflow is the only one that seems to be wonky for me...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been caused by using Python version 3.8, which is currently an unsupported version of Python. Once I created a new Anaconda environment with Python version 3.7 this issue went away.

The only remaining issue is this error that I see when I run `pip install -e .` for my project which includes tensorflow:

```
ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 1.15.0rc2 has requirement tensorboard<1.16.0,>=1.15.0, but you'll have tensorboard 2.1.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-cpu 1.15.0rc2 has requirement tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1, but you'll have tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0 which is incompatible.
```

So the issue of `tensorflow-cpu` version 1.15.0rc2 actually being installed when version 2.1.0 shows as being the installed version is still a mystery. To wit:

```
$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/james/miniconda3/envs/cvd:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
1.15.0-rc2
```